# Parse.com - associating a push notification installation object id to user

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I am not sure how to associate a push notification installation object id to a particular user. Is there some sort of meta data that can be sent to connect a user id of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Associate the device with a user
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

This will put the user in a column "user" in the Installation table, the column would be a pointer to the _User table.

Here is how how would send a push targeting by user, assuming your user table has a "firstName" column:

```
// Find users
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"firstName" equalTo:"Bob"];

// Find devices associated with these users
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:userQuery];

// Send push notification to query
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
[push setMessage:@"Hi Bob, thanks for using my app!"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: is this automatically done in the push notifications starter app?

Comment: @Ina I don't know, I don't have the code for that in front of me. You could look through it and try to find it, though.

Comment: i'm still not sure how to reference the user to the push notification. can you outline the variable name?